# sql server full index search partial word and full word

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table like this:

Key     SearchTexts
KZ78    Aberdeen American Equity A Acc, KZ78, GB00B0XWN143, ,

My sql query is:

```
select * from dbunits.dbo.fxUnitSearch where CONTAINS(searchText, '"Aberdeen American Equity A Acc*"')
```

However, it returns no data. If I do this:

```
select * from dbunits.dbo.fxUnitSearch where CONTAINS(searchText, '"Aberdeen American Equity A Acc"')
```

Then it returns. I thought 'xxx*' will partial search, which should work for exact match as well?

What am I doing wrong here?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use FREETEXT instead of CONTAINS

```
select * from dbunits.dbo.fxUnitSearch where FREETEXT (searchText, '"Aberdeen American Equity A Acc*"')
```